# Compaq 15-s103TX Notebook PC RAM Dimensions : 7.6 x 2.5 x 1 cm & 10.4 x 8.9 x 1 cm

Tags: laptop, memory

Today I opened my [Compaq 15-s103TX Notebook PC](http://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04519551) and found that it has an empty RAM slot. So I thought of upgrading it to 8GB RAM (old 4GB + New 4GB).

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and here is the output of `sudo dmidecode` (system details):

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
59 structures occupying 2945 bytes.
Table at 0x9CEAC000.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 221, 12 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 0C 00 00 01 01 00 01 07 00 00 00
    Strings:
        Reference Code - ACPI

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: 0x0008
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0001
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-Slot 1(left)
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Empty
    Serial Number: Empty
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: Empty
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0001
    Error Information Handle: 0x0006
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Hynix
    Serial Number: 2211125B
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: HMT451S6BFR8A-PB
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0004
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0009
    Partition Row Position: 1
    Interleave Position: 2
    Interleaved Data Depth: 1

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0001
    Partition Width: 2

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Insyde
    Version: F.39
    Release Date: 05/26/2015
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 6144 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
        Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 15.57
    Firmware Revision: 86.52

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: Compaq 15 Notebook PC
    Version: 0990110000000000000600087
    Serial Number: CND446CL46
    UUID: 0F8D7781-7668-E411-B2A0-ECB1D7BE0333
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: K8T82PA#ACJ
    Family: 103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=CO S=PRE  

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 2, 16 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: 2212
    Version: 86.52
    Serial Number: PEHYFH21T7PGIH
    Asset Tag: Type2 - Board Asset Tag
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
    Chassis Handle: 0x000E
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 3, 23 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Type: Notebook
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: Chassis Version
    Serial Number: Chassis Serial Number
    Asset Tag: Chassis Asset Tag
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: Not Specified

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Keyboard
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Mouse
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: COM 1
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J5A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J5A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J5A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Network
    External Connector Type: RJ-45
    Port Type: Network Port

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9G2
    Internal Connector Type: On Board Floppy
    External Reference Designator: OnBoard Floppy Type
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J7J1
    Internal Connector Type: On Board IDE
    External Reference Designator: OnBoard Primary IDE
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: TV OUT
    External Connector Type: Mini DIN
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: CRT
    External Connector Type: DB-15 female
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J30
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Microphone In
    External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
    Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J30
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Line In
    External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
    Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J30
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Speaker Out
    External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
    Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J5C1
    Type: x16 PCI Express x16
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 1
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:01.0

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6C1
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.0

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6C2
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 3
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.1

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6D2
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 4
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.2

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J7C1
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 5
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.3

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J7D2
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 6
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.4

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J8C1
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 7
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.5

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J8C2
    Type: x16 PCI Express x16
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 8
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.7

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: $HP$
    String 2: LOC#   
    String 3: ABS 70/71 78 79 7A 7B
    String 4: CNB1 0990110000000000000600087
    String 5: HP_Mute_LED_0_A
    String 6: String6 for Original Equipment Manufacturer
    String 7: String7 for Original Equipment Manufacturer
    String 8: String8 for Original Equipment Manufacturer
    String 9: String9 for Original Equipment Manufacturer
    String 10: String10 for Original Equipment Manufacturer
    String 11: String11 for Original Equipment Manufacturer

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: String1 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 2: String2 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 3: String3 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 4: String4 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 5: String5 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 6: String6 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 7: String7 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 8: String8 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 5
        en|U
        |iso8859-1
        fr|CA|iso8859-1
        es|ES|iso8859-1
        zh|TW|unicode
    Currently Installed Language: en|U

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 15, 29 bytes
System Event Log
    Area Length: 0 bytes
    Header Start Offset: 0x0000
    Header Length: 32 bytes
    Data Start Offset: 0x0020
    Access Method: General-purpose non-volatile data functions
    Access Address: 0x0000
    Status: Valid, Not Full
    Change Token: 0x12345678
    Header Format: OEM-specific
    Supported Log Type Descriptors: 3
    Descriptor 1: POST memory resize
    Data Format 1: None
    Descriptor 2: POST error
    Data Format 2: POST results bitmap
    Descriptor 3: Log area reset/cleared
    Data Format 3: None

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 21, 7 bytes
Built-in Pointing Device
    Type: Touch Pad
    Interface: PS/2
    Buttons: 4

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 22, 26 bytes
Portable Battery
    Location: Primary
    Manufacturer: 13-42
    Manufacture Date: 01/01/2013
    Serial Number: SERIAL
    Name: OA04041
    Chemistry: Lithium Ion
    Design Capacity: 41440 mWh
    Design Voltage: 14800 mV
    SBDS Version: 1
    Maximum Error: 1%
    OEM-specific Information: 0x000B050D

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 24, 5 bytes
Hardware Security
    Power-On Password Status: Disabled
    Keyboard Password Status: Disabled
    Administrator Password Status: Disabled
    Front Panel Reset Status: Disabled

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 26, 22 bytes
Voltage Probe
    Description: Voltage Probe Description.
    Location: Unknown
    Status: Unknown
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 27, 15 bytes
Cooling Device
    Type: Fan
    Status: OK
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Speed: 2000 rpm
    Description: Cooling Device Description.

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 39, 22 bytes
System Power Supply
    Location: OEM_Define0
    Name: OEM_Define1
    Manufacturer: OEM_Define2
    Serial Number: OEM_Define3
    Asset Tag: OEM_Define4
    Model Part Number: OEM_Define5
    Revision: OEM_Define6
    Max Power Capacity: 75 W
    Status: Present, OK
    Type: Regulator
    Input Voltage Range Switching: Auto-switch
    Plugged: No
    Hot Replaceable: No
    Cooling Device Handle: 0x002F

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 40, 18 bytes
Additional Information 1
    Referenced Handle: 0x001f
    Referenced Offset: 0x05
    String: PCIExpressx16
    Value: 0xaa
Additional Information 2
    Referenced Handle: 0x000b
    Referenced Offset: 0x05
    String: Compiler Version: VC 9.0
    Value: 0x05dc

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Skyray
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:0a:00.0

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 136, 6 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        88 06 34 00 FF FF

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 128, 8 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        80 08 35 00 55 AA 55 AA
    Strings:
        Oem Test 1
        Oem Test 2

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 129, 8 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        81 08 36 00 01 01 02 01
    Strings:
        Intel_ASF
        Intel_ASF_001

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 130, 20 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        82 14 37 00 24 41 4D 54 01 01 01 01 01 A5 9F 02
        00 00 01 00

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: U3E1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Core i3
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    ID: 51 06 04 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 69, Stepping 1
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz
    Voltage: 0.7 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 1700 MHz
    Current Speed: 1700 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Socket BGA1168
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x003A
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x003B
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x003C
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 4
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
        Execute Protection
        Enhanced Virtualization
        Power/Performance Control

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 32 kB
    Maximum Size: 32 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 32 kB
    Maximum Size: 32 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Instruction
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 256 kB
    Maximum Size: 256 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x003C, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L3 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 3072 kB
    Maximum Size: 3072 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 12-way Set-associative

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

You can see that My Ram Specs are :

- Manufacturer: Hynix
- Part Number: HMT451S6BFR8A-PB

I found two similar RAMS on Amazon.

- [Hynix 4gb Ddr3 Memory So-dimm 204pin Pc3l-12800s 1600mhz " **HMT451S6BFR8A-PB** "](http://www.amazon.in/Memory-So-dimm-Pc3l-12800s-1600mhz-Hmt451s6bfr8a-pb/dp/B016GKBY4S?ie=UTF8&keywords=HMT451S6BFR8A-PB&qid=1465134494&ref_=nav_signin&sr=8-1)
- [Hynix " **HMT351S6CFR8C-PB** " 4GB PC3-12800S DDR3 1600MHz non-ECC Unbuffered Memory](http://www.amazon.in/Hynix-HMT351S6CFR8C-PB-PC3-12800S-1600MHz-Unbuffered/dp/B00A8J2OUM/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1465134970&sr=8-3&keywords=hynix%204gb%20ddr3%20laptop%20ram)

But I am confused with the **Dimensions**:

The first product (Exact part number) Dimensions are given as **7.6 x 2.5 x 1 cm**.

But the second product (Same specs but slightly different part number) dimensions are given as **10.4 x 8.9 x 1 cm**.

Do RAM dimensions vary from laptop to laptop? Or there is only one standard RAM Dimension (for notebooks) and the dimensions given on those Amazon listings is a mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got talked about on chat.

There's one standard size for ram for laptops, though DDR3 has standard (1.5v) and low voltage variations (1.35v). Your laptop will *definitely* work with low voltage (PC3L) ram, and that's the safe bet. The other ram may or may not work.

The formfactor is *identical*, and in most cases different families of ram of the same 'type' - say SODIMM vs DIMM are differenciated by where a notch is, rather than a major change in size and shape

Comment: +1 and  ☑ :  "The other ram may or may not work" . Thanks , thats all I needed. I will buy the perfect match :D

Answer (score 1):

For DDR3/DDR3L 204pin SODIMMs the correct dimension should be,

67.6mm X 30mm

Reference:

[image]

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Laptop_SODIMM_DDR_Memory_Comparison_V2.svg/744px-Laptop_SODIMM_DDR_Memory_Comparison_V2.svg.png]